# TextBox KeyDown Trigger Event not working for Backspace and Delete key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a Textbox and for that textbox I have attached a keydown event. Everything is working fine but I just noticed that when i'm pressing the 'Backspace' and 'Delete' Key, the binding command is not being called.

**My View xaml file :-**

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Width="500" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>                
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">  
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{BindingPath=TextBoxKeyDownEvent}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />                
    </i:EventTrigger>            
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

**My ViewModel cs file :-**

```
    //TextBox Key Down Event Handler
    private DelegateCommand _textBoxKeyDownEvent;
    public ICommand TextBoxKeyDownEvent
    {
        get
        {
            if (_textBoxKeyDownEvent == null)
            {
                _textBoxKeyDownEvent = new DelegateCommand(TextBoxKeyDownEventHandler);
            }
            return _textBoxKeyDownEvent;
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Can somebody give me some suggestion

Comment: The `EventToCommand` is a blackbox you need to dig into.

Comment: You could use a KeyBinding - but your TextBoxText property is updated I guess. Why do you need to capture the Keys when you are notified when the text changes?

Comment: @kallocaion:Thanks for your answer. Bur for my case Binding textProperty will not work. Because the program will change the content of the textbox dynamically and then i don't want to call my eventHandler. I have other event associated with the same component and that'm i'm not able to switch to other event like keyup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:**
You have to use `PreviewKeyDown` the it works. KeyDown is not fired on Space and Delete. If you ignore MVVM and put the handler of `KeyDown` in codebehind it **will also fail**.

---

How about binding the Text-Property to a string in you viewmodel?

I build a fast, simple example of my idea.

**Result**

Text from the TextBox on the left side is simply populated to the Textblock on the right side.

[image]

**View**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Width="250"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>"</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextBoxValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            <TextBlock>"</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string textBoxValue;

    public string TextBoxValue
    {
        get { return textBoxValue; }
        set
        {
            textBoxValue = value;
            OnTextBoxValueChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    void OnTextBoxValueChanged()
    {
        // you logic here, if needed.
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Bur for my case Binding textProperty will not work. Because the program will change the content of the textbox dynamically and then i don't want to call my eventHandler. I have other event associated with the same component and that'm i'm not able to switch to other event like keyup.

Comment: Thanks ec80r. You are correct. I have to use PreviewKeyDown. Its working now.

Answer (score 3):

you most use PreviewKeyDown event.

Like this:

```
 <EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: You are correct - the default behavior is not executed. You should use ec8ors solution, which is much better anyway:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Width="500" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TextBoxKeyDownEvent, Mode=OneWay}"/>
       </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

**Original**:
You can use InputBindings to call your command when "special" keys have been pressed:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" Width="500" Text="{Binding TextBoxText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>                
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">  
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{BindingPath=TextBoxKeyDownEvent}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />                
      </i:EventTrigger>            
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>

   <TextBox.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxKeyDownEvent}" Key="Delete" />
      <KeyBinding Command="{Binding TextBoxKeyDownEvent}" Key="Back" />
   </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I tried your approach. But in that case the keybinding method is being called and executed  but Delete and Back key loss their default behavior. That means they are not deleting the content from cursor position.